# How to set navigation mode to 3d with SKNavigationManager in Skobbler maps?

Tags: android, skmaps

I have added code for getting map view in 3D but its not working. Map is always coming in 2d mode.

Here's my `mapView` settings

```
mapView.getMapSettings().setMapDisplayMode(SKMapDisplayMode.MODE_3D)
```

Here's my code for starting navigation

```
SKNavigationSettings navigationSettings = new SKNavigationSettings();
navigationSettings.setNavigationType(SKNavigationType.SIMULA‌​TION); 
navigationSettings.setDistanceUnit(SKDistanceUnitType.DISTAN‌CE_UNIT_MILES_FEET); 
SKNavigationManager navigationManager = SKNavigationManager.getInstance(); 
System.out.println("Navigation MOde >>>>> "+navigationManager.getNavigationMode()); 
navigationManager.setMapView(mapView);
navigationManager.setNavigationListener(this); 
navigationManager.startNavigation(navigationSettings);
```

Comment: Please add also the code you are using to configure navigation in 3D.

Comment: Here's my code for starting navigation       


SKNavigationSettings navigationSettings = new SKNavigationSettings();
     navigationSettings.setNavigationType(SKNavigationType.SIMULATION);
     navigationSettings.setDistanceUnit(SKDistanceUnitType.DISTANCE_UNIT_MILES_FEET);
     SKNavigationManager navigationManager = SKNavigationManager.getInstance();
     System.out.println("Navigation MOde >>>>> "+navigationManager.getNavigationMode());
     navigationManager.setMapView(mapView);
     navigationManager.setNavigationListener(this);
     navigationManager.startNavigation(navigationSettings);

Comment: Please add this code in the question. What are your mapView settings?

Comment: @ando, I addplied this code


mapView.getMapSettings().setMapDisplayMode(SKMapDisplayMode.MODE_3D);

But its not working.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for this.

Problem was not in the code but when is was running the application from eclipse it was showing 2D maps, but when I open the application directly from mobile, It worked !!!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you've managed to get it working (as a general suggestion - please test your app directly on a device as the Android emulators are rather unreliable (especially when emulating OpenGL logic))

Comment: hi!, Yes I tested it on device but still it was not coming up with 3D maps when i run app from eclipse in device but same file was working fine when i launch it from device. :)